# Meteor 1.7 without MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to run a Meteor project, where I don't use Accounts nor any other Mongo Collection, and therefore would like to run the project without a Mongo DB server.

I've researched and found a few resources, mostly very old, none of which work with a current 1.7.x version of Meteor.

Anyone out there successfully made a recent Meteor version work without Mongo DB?

Comment: Client only or is server required?

Comment: Both actually... that is, I want to run the server without having to connect to a mongo db server. Neither client nor server am I using mongo collections...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove mongo by looking through your packages for things that depend on `mongo` or `mongo-dev-server` with `meteor list --tree`

On a fresh app this means removing:

- `mongo` - obviously
- `meteor-base`, and
- `autopublish`

by running:

```
meteor remove mongo meteor-base autopublish
```

It turns out `meteor-base` has some important stuff in it that we want, so we want to add back in:

- `meteor`
- `ddp` - pub/sub and meteor methods
- `webapp` - Serves the app bundle to the client

by running:

```
meteor add ddp webapp meteor
```

Note that you will lose hot code reloading on the client as that also depends on mongo :(

Comment: It works, thanks very much. I noticed that after this change, the package alexwine:bootstrap-4 is failing to import the bootstrap files into the client. Are you aware of any known issue with packages when applying these changes? Would there be perhaps any missing package to be added manually (which was included in meteor-base) to bring such functionality back?

Comment: Ok, found the issue.. the `meteor` package must also be installed, otherwise `css` is not imported into the client. Updated the answer to include this info.